# Android table background color

Tags: android, background

To simulate a grid, I have a tablelayout with background `#ffffff`, tablerow with background `#000000` and textviews with background `#dcdcdc`.

The entire cell is colored #dcdcdc when the textview has width and height set in fill_parent, but when I add the attribute `layout_gravity=center`, the width fill_parent attribute is discarded. How can I center the text keeping the whole cell with the expected color?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a `TableView` to simulate a grid instead of a `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly...you can use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

on the TextView to center the text in the view.